# Input HTML code in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a header string, footer string and body of the HTML page. I need to programmatically include some text in the `body` and then I need to input all this data in a `UIWebView` to load the page. I need to input the final HTML string into a `UIWebView` controler, so that it will launch the page I designed. Could someone please share your ideas how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you any code regarding that or not?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. No, i didn't find any tutorial how to go ahead on this. But, I am only seeing how to read js or html files from directory and execute that page.

Comment: [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><head><style>body{background-color:black}</style></head><body>the body goes here</body>"];    
UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,76.0,320.0,404.0)];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

If you, for example, have head stored in headString and body in bodyString you could combine them with:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html>%@%@</html>", headString, bodyString];
```

Comment: @rokjarc How would you include a http header (i.e. 'Accept-Language: en-US' or 'Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ')?

Comment: @ConfusedDeer: hmm, `head` in my answer refers to the `<head>` tag. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24683201/653513) you could set the headers in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`. I didn't try it though.