# How to set http header in uiwebview if loading view with loadHTMLString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that i am loading using `loadHTMLString` and i need to set cookies on the request header. I know how to do this using `loadRequest` but not loading the webview with `loadHTMLString` I don't have the request object. Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: there will not be any difference between loading web view from loadRequest vs loadHTMLString method, shouldStartLoadWithRequest method will be called in both cases. You can override your headers there.

Comment: BOOM! that seemed to do the trick! thanks!

Comment: Good, might be this can be posted as answer and you can accept and close the question!!

Comment: @DeprecatedDarren please can you tell me how you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be any difference between loading web view from loadRequest vs loadHTMLString method, shouldStartLoadWithRequest method will be called in both cases. You can override your headers there and add header as per your requirements.

Comment: i have the same issue while loading HTML string with  loadHTMLString and than add header field in shouldStartLoadWithRequest and than load request my loaded HTML is getting blank

Comment: after loading HTML, you want to change header fields in shouldStartLoadRequest?

Comment: Thanks for reply rishi, Yes I want but the issue is when is update header and then load request which is in shouldStartLoadRequest so my HTML is getting blank.