# Override headers in NSURLRequest from shouldStartLoadWithRequest uiwebviewdelegate method?

Tags: ios, uiwebviewdelegate

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682722/how-to-set-http-header-in-uiwebview-if-loading-view-with-loadhtmlstring) question they stated that "you can override your headers" in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest uiwebviewdelegate method. How would I do that? I thought you can only add headers to a NSMutableURLRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he doesn't mean that headers will be overridden in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest
he mean that headers can be overridden using NSMutableURLRequest in both loadHTMLString and loadRequest